# How to force windows to render a specific monitor as its mirror image

Tags: windows, winapi, graphics, driver, win32gui

Is it possible to create a program that intercepts the video output to a specific monitor and flips the image about the y-axis. I have found one program called UltraMon that lets you display one monitor as the mirror Image of another but I want to set one monitor to mirror its own input signal.  I can easily mirror the output of my own code but I would like the windows desktop and any arbitrary software running to be mirrored as well. Is there a way to hook into the rendering pipeline of windows?

Edit: 
I know there is a fliped option in Nvidia's Control Panel but this is just a 180deg rotation. I am looking for the true mirror image such that when viewing the monitor through a single mirror the imgage appears normal. i.e. for normilaized pixel coords x = (1-x)

Comment: Most graphics drivers can do this as a built in feature - they usually have rotation settings which include "flipped" as an option.

Comment: The "flipped" option in most graphics card drivers such as the Nvida Control Panel is really just a rotation.  It seems "flipped" in that use simple means rotated 180deg from horizontal or vertical. I am looking for the mirror image i.e. for normalized pixel position (x = 1-x)